# how to read events from google calendar in titanium

Tags: titanium, google-calendar-api

i am developing an app for IOS/Android in which i need to read the events from google calendar. i started with OAuth 2.0 for titanium and got the access token but how am i suppose to get the list of calendars and events using this access token.

I tried this:-

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?access_token = "+accessToken;
       var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
            onload: function(e) {
              var calendar = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);

            },
            onerror: function(e) {
                Ti.API.debug(e.error);
                alert('error');
            },
            timeout:15000
        });

        xhr.open("GET", url);
        xhr.send();
```

It give me "Authentication needed" error.

Any Help?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try removing whitespaces in `access_token = "+accessToken;`

Comment: Thank you for your reply @daniula. I tried it but it gives me same "authentication needed" error. Any Thoughts?